# JQuery plugins: call options function with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

http://jsbin.com/cudedaramo/2/edit?html,css,js,output

I wrote basic Jquery plugin with some options parameter:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.clicks= function(options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            whenclick : null
        }, options);


        $(".click").on("click",function(){
                  settings.whenclick.call( this );

        });

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Call this plugin:

```
$(".clickable").clicks({
  whenclick: function (){
    alert("ok");
  }
});
```

i want to pass some parameter to options function, example:

```
 $(".clickable").clicks({
      whenclick: function (a){
        alert(a);
      }
    });
```

In this situation, to get the ID of clicked button, the code must change like:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.clicks= function(options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            whenclick : null
        }, options);


        $(".click").on("click",function(){
                  settings.whenclick.call( $(this).attr("id") );

        });

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

but this code not work, i am trying to pass id of clicked button to *"options function"*.

```
$(".click").on("click",function(){
                      settings.whenclick.call( $(this).attr("id") );

            });
```

**I want to know how passing parameter like this, not display the button Id.**

Comment: None of the elements have an ID ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sn2um0om/

Comment: thanks adeneo, but i am still not know why alert(this) is working?
can you explain me?

Comment: The first argument for `call` is what `this` will be set to in the called function, so if you pass an ID as the first argument, `this` inside the function ***is*** that ID. Go to MDN and read the documentation for `call`